# How to join two tables (multi row) in Django

Tags: python, django

I want to join 2 tables from 2 tables, such as 'auth_user' and 'polls_account'. How I can join them?

models.py

```
class Account(models.Model):
    usid = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    ROLE = (
        ('01', 'Owner-Manager'),
        ('02', 'Staff'),
    )
    role = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=ROLE, blank=True, null=True)
```

views.py

```
def useraccount(request):
    user_list = User.objects.all()
    userlist = {
        'user_list': user_list,
    return render(request, 'polls/useraccount.html', userlist)
    }
```

I need to show table according this

```
| username | firstname | lastname |   role   |
----------------------------------------------
|    a     |   Mike    |   Hanze  |   Staff  |
```

And, should I change 'usid' to 'OneToOneField'?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you really want each User to have multiple Accounts, use OneToOneField instead of ForeignKey. Like this:

```
usid = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Then in your template:

```
{% for user in userlist %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ user.username }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.firstname }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.lastname }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.account.role }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```